# Excel: Hyperlink to a cell specified by another cell's value

Tags: excel

I have a document that needs to generate a hyperlink to a cell in the same workbook by getting the address from another cell. Here's what I have right now:

```
=hyperlink(CELL("address",INDEX('Budget Record'!C3:C105,MATCH(Y73,'Budget Record'!C3:C105,0),1)))
```

This displays the appropriate location:

```
'[Calendar Budget.xlsx]Budget Record'!$C$3
```

However, when clicked, it says that Excel cannot open the specified file.

I have tried manually creating a hyperlink to that value, and it still doesn't appear to work:

```
=hyperlink('[Calendar Budget.xlsx]Budget Record'!$C$3)
```

However, if I plug that into the goto dialogue box, it has no problems with it.

Am I missing an extra step?

Comment: if `Calendar Budget.xlsx` is closed, the link will need the full path.

Comment: Calendar Budget.xlsx is actually the same workbook. I tried making an extra step where the [Calendar Budget.xlsx] part is removed, and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into all of the built-in hyperlink options that Excel offers, I could not find a way to have Excel link you to a dynamic/ changing cell reference.  Naturally, I turned to VBA :)... this is a very simple macro with only a few lines of code.  Give it try:

1. Press Alt + 11 to open the Visual Basic Editor (VBE)
2. If your project explorer is not already open, click this icon: [image: CRUTER - VBE Project Explorer icon]
3. Double click the worksheet tab that you want the hyperlink to work on: [image: CRUTER - VBE project explorer sheet name]
4. Paste the following code into the white space:

   ```
   Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

       'check if user is selecting the 'hyperlink' cell
       If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then

           'run the 'selectCell()' subroutine
           Call selectCell

       End If

   End Sub

   Sub selectCell()

       Dim goToAddress As String

       'get cell address
       goToAddress = Range("A2").Value

       'send user to this cell
       Range(goToAddress).Select

   End Sub
   ```
5. Go to your worksheet and test the script by typing `G3` in cell `B1`.
6. Select cell `A1`.  The macro should have automatically selected cell `G3`.

Hope this helps!

[image: CRUTER - VBE image as a reference]

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I have identified a solution. Basically it looks like the problem was in the formatting.

Basically I needed three steps. The first one is getting the location of the cell returned as a full address (including the file, sheet, and Cell). I do that with this:

```
=CELL("address",INDEX('Budget Record'!C3:C105,MATCH(Y73,'Budget Record'!C3:C105,0),1))
```

Here's a sample of what that results in:

```
'[Calendar Budget.xlsx]Budget Record'!$C$3
```

The problem with this is that the apostrophe at the beginning is in the wrong spot. To work as a hyperlink, the string should be this:

```
[Calendar Budget.xlsx]'Budget Record'!$C$3
```

So, I have a step where I remove the first 22 characters of the starting string:

```
=RIGHT(Z73,LEN(Z73)-23)
```

This results in the following:

```
Budget Record'!$C$3
```

Next, I need to add on this to the start of the string:

```
[Calendar Budget.xlsx]'
```

I do that with the following:

```
=HYPERLINK("[Calendar Budget.xlsx]'"&AA73)
```

The resulting output looks like this:

```
[Calendar Budget.xlsx]'Budget Record'!$C$3
```

So, we have a hyperlink to a cell in another sheet that dynamically changes depending on the initial referenced cell.